# proguard removing things I specified with keep

Tags: java, proguard

I'm trying to configure proguard to only shrink my jar and also to only remove fields in the packages com.faster.xml**, com.amazonaws.javax.**, com.amazonaws.org.apache.**, org.apache.commons.**, and org.joda.**. To do this, I've used the following in my proguard config:

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-keepattributes

-keep enum ** { *; }
-keep class !com.fasterxml.**, !com.amazonaws.javax.**,
        !com.amazonaws.org.apache.**, !org.apache.commons.**, !org.joda.**,
        ** { *; }
```

However, I've noticed that things which are not in the namespaces specified are still getting removed. The jar still appears to be working, but I just wanted to understand what it's doing exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration explicitly preserves all classes, fields, and methods, except the ones in the specified packages. That should be what you want. You can check the effect of your configuration with

```
-printseeds seeds.txt
```

The generated file contains a list of the explicitly preserved classes, fields, and methods.

If some classes seem to disappear, you should double-check the input directories or input jars. You can also check if the `-injars` or `-outjars` options in your configuration have filters.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I was using some utility to count methods by namespace and some of them went missing after using proguard. However, they don't appear in the seeds file. Could it be that proguard is doing some inlining or other magic or is there something else happening?

Comment: The -keep options preserve the specified classes, fields, and methods from shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization. ProGuard also writes the seeds file right after having read the input, before any processing. You should check your input: ProGuard lists the files and directories that it reads, and you can check the methods with javap.